# how to get data from state reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have data and when I show with sintax `console.log(this.state.product)` the data show correctly, here the output in console:
[image]

now I want to get harga produk from the output, I use this sintax `console.log(this.state.product.harga.produk)` but I get the error, how to do that? I want to get data that marked red line
[image]

Comment: It should be `this.state.product.data.harga.produk`.

Comment: thats not working

Comment: Then either your question is wrong, or there's something up with asynchronous code. Post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because your `this.state.product` still empty (default state declared in constructor).

before console.log make sure this.state.product is filled with the required data.

so you have to turn it into something like this in rendering

```
if (this.state.product.status && this.state.product.status ==200) {
 console.log(this.state.product.data.harga)
}
```